# How to fill value to a UID directly in SAP B1 UI API?

Tags: c#, api, user-interface, sapb1

I have following setup:

```
SAPbouiCOM.Form oForm = SwissAddonFramework.B1Connector.GetB1Connector().Application.Forms.ActiveForm;
```

I want to write directly a value (Empty String / Space) to a uid (user defined field), it´s called: "U_KAS_LP".

How does that work?

Comment: For information of people, the code concerns CoreSuite Framework (B1 add-on).

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
Dim db As SAPbouiCOM.DBDataSource = oForm.DataSources.DBDataSources.Item("YourSapTable")                                            
db.SetValue("U_KAS_LP", 0, "")
```

You just need to know the table name,  or try the default:

```
DBDataSources.Item(0)
```